Replace values in data frame if value is greater or smaller depending on values in first column
I have problem manipulating my big data-frame in R. This seems to be a basic thing in R, but I can't find a solution.
Dummy example for df:
   threshold  V1    V2     V3      V4
#1    10       1   100      2     200
#2    20      10    50     20     100
#3    30      50    10    100      20
#4    40     100     1    200       2

All values in column 2,3,4 and 5 should be renamed depending on the value in the first column of the corresponding row:
That means for values in the first row:
If the value is smaller than the value in the first column and first row _(here 10), then return 1, otherwise 0.
That for values in the second row:
If the value is smaller than the value in the first column and second row (here 20), then return 1, otherwise 0.
etc.
The result should look like this:
   threshold  V1    V2   V3   V4
#1    10       1    0    1     0
#2    20       1    0    0     0
#3    30       0    1    0     1
#4    40       0    1    0     1

I tried it with apply and lapply,
for example this:
df[2:5] <- lapply(df[2:5], function(x,y) ifelse(x < df[y,1], 1, 0))

but it gives me wrong results. I still struggle with this code.
Can you please give some advice on how to proceed? Any help is highly appreciated!

If your data is not too large, looping might be ok. Try X[-1] = +t(apply(X, 1L, \(x) x[1] < x[-1])), where X is your data (df--I would prefer df0 as a data frame name) and its first column is the threshold.

A looping approach over each row: X[-1] = +t(apply(X, 1L, \(x) x[1] > x[-1])).
> X = read.table(text="threshold  V1    V2     V3      V4
+     10       1   100      2     200
+     20      10    50     20     100
+     30      50    10    100      20
+     40     100     1    200       2", header = TRUE)
> 
> # X[-1] =
> +t(apply(X, 1L, \(x) x[1] > x[-1]))
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  1  0  1  0
[2,]  1  0  0  0
[3,]  0  1  0  1
[4,]  0  1  0  1


Thank you very much! :D  This solution fits with my data and I even learned a few things in R from this solution.

You can play the following trick
> df[-1] <- +(df[-1] < df[[1]])

> df
  threshold V1 V2 V3 V4
1        10  1  0  1  0
2        20  1  0  0  0
3        30  0  1  0  1
4        40  0  1  0  1


Thank you very much! :D  Wow, I didn't expect such a short solution, but it worked with my data. After that I just had to convert the array to dataframe

@MadRugada I just assumed you are working on dataframe
